# Android GeoPoints of Cities or States

Tags: android, geopoints

Suppose I want to find out the GeoPoints of WashingtonDC from the sourcecode of eclipse is it possible or i have to store all the GeoPoints from the net in another file

then where i can find the list of geopoints of all the cities/Airports of the world??

Comment: please make your question more descriptive.

Comment: is there any built in method to findout the GeoPoints of washingtonDC??

Comment: you want it in your android app?

Comment: Yes.. :) so that i dont have to store the GeoPoints of a specific city
it just find out from the library... :)

Comment: search for geocoding and reverse geocoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Siddhesh mentioned check out the class [Android.location.Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).  Also this requires 
"a backend service that is not included in the core android framework" so you might want to make sure it is available with a call to isPresent().